# Using Selenium to select a specific download button when there are many seemingly identical download buttons on the same page

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm using an online educational platform that's generating daily excel spreadsheets. When I access my portal, I can click on a specific day or see a list of days, each with an inline download button. I'm new to Selenium in Python and I'm trying to download some or all of them from the list page.
[Here is a screenshot of an example list. The "Download Excel" button is in the drop-down at the end of each entry in the list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eS6td.png) 
[Here is a screenshot of the Inspection of the download button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/al8ds.png)

I haven't been able to find any css id, html, xpath etc. distinction to specify which of the download buttons I want to click. When I tried just specifiying the css selector, only the top item of the list was downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get all the buttons and click only the ones you want.

```
# Find all
download_buttons = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="download-button"]/button')

specific_button_index = 2 # the index of the button
download_buttons[specific_button_index].click()
```